# Extract numerical data from product description

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I am working with python3.

I am trying to pull out numerical data from a product description.  Sometimes however the same product has a differently worded description which results in conflicting results.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data = {'desc':['1 oz Silver Eagles Monster Box  (500 pc)', 'Silver Eagle Monster Box (500 pcs 1 oz coins)', '2021 10 oz Silver Royal Canadian Mint Bar'], 'inventory':['in stock', 'in stock', 'out of stock']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['ounces']=df['desc'].str.extract(r'(\d+ pc|\d+ oz)')
print(df)
```

What i get is:

```
                                            desc     inventory  ounces
0       1 oz Silver Eagles Monster Box  (500 pc)      in stock    1 oz
1  Silver Eagle Monster Box (500 pcs 1 oz coins)      in stock  500 pc
2      2021 10 oz Silver Royal Canadian Mint Bar  out of stock   10 oz
```

Clearly the first 2 items are the same. I expected regex to look for 'pc' first in the entire description and then if nothing found look for 'oz' but that is not what it does.  What I need to get is:

```
                                            desc     inventory  ounces
0       1 oz Silver Eagles Monster Box  (500 pc)      in stock  500 pc
1  Silver Eagle Monster Box (500 pcs 1 oz coins)      in stock  500 pc
2      2021 10 oz Silver Royal Canadian Mint Bar  out of stock   10 oz
```

My original dataframe does not have ounces and i am trying to add that column and extract the correct data at the same time.  Should I be going about this differently?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
>>> df['ounces'] = df['desc'].str.findall(r'(?:.*\D)?(\d+ pc)|(\d+ oz)').str[0].str.join('')
>>> df
                                            desc     inventory  ounces
0       1 oz Silver Eagles Monster Box  (500 pc)      in stock  500 pc
1  Silver Eagle Monster Box (500 pcs 1 oz coins)      in stock  500 pc
2      2021 10 oz Silver Royal Canadian Mint Bar  out of stock   10 oz
```

The `(?:.*\D)?(\d+ pc)|(\d+ oz)` pattern will give priority to the first capturing group that matches `pc`, and the `oz` part will only get matched if it occurs after the `pc` one.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pyQM4B/1).

Since `Series.str.findall` returns all pattern matches, `.str[0]` is required to obtain the first result only, and `.str.join('')` convert the tuple (as there are two groups in the pattern, `findall` returns list of tuples) into a string (since one of the group values will always be empty).

Comment: Thanks for that.  Can the pattern be expanded if there are more than 2 possible things or must it be a tuple?

Comment: @Jamie It can be expanded.